# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'float' with numpy.zeros

Tags: python, numpy, addition, nonetype

i'm currently working on a linear classifier and trying to add two matrices. But elements of one of my matrix are considered 'NoneType'. I don't know why.

image

[image: 1]

```
lamb_diag = np.zeros((N,N), float)
lamb_diag = np.fill_diagonal(lamb_diag, self.lamb)

sigma = lamb_diag + sigma
```

Here lamb_diag elements are considered NoneType.

I tried to force elements to be floats but it doesn't work.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: What is self.lamb or sigma? It's hard to debug without seeing a fuller picture

Comment: From the `numpy.fill_diagonal` [docs:](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.fill_diagonal.html) _...This function modifies the input array in-place, **it does not return a value.**_

Answer (score 0):

`fill_diagonal` function is inplace, meaning the output of the method is None, so you shouldn't assign back to `lamb_diag`.

```
lamb_diag = np.zeros((N,N), float)
np.fill_diagonal(lamb_diag, self.lamb) # *

sigma = lamb_diag + sigma
```